# User ID increases the number of users in GA

Tags: google-analytics

Yesterday I notice a strange issue in Google Analytics and I was wondering if someone has the answer.

I created a custom report in GA, using as dimensions: Campaign, Date and Device Category, and as metrics: Cost, Users, Revenue and Clicks.

After creating this particular report, there was the need to use the UserId dimension, as a secondary.

What I observed is that when I put UserId as a secondary dimension, the number of users changes significantly. Does anyone happen to know, why this is happening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What date range are you querying?

Comment: I'm doing a daily search, because I'm interested about cost per user. Actually, that phenomenon happens into specific days. Other days are ok, I guess, with ±10 Users.